# How to use an asynchronous function inside a then ()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to make my AsyncStorage setItem only run after the promise (then) is completed.

```
  viewShot.current.capture().then(uri => {
    page = uri;

    //---------------------------------------------------
      try {
        const dataSave = {
          key: '1',
          title: 'Page One',

        };
        pagina.pushScreen.push(dataSave);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@pages', JSON.stringify(pagina));
        // alert('Página Salva!');
      } catch (e) {
        alert('Erro ao salvar página');
      }
      //-----------------------------------------------------

  });
```

[image]

Comment: `.then(async (uri) => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

See how `await` is underlined with an error squiggle? Hover over it and read the error.

You can only await inside an `async` function which `uri => { ... }` is not.

Mark it as async:

```
then( async (uri) => { ... } );
```

Better yet, don't use `then` in the first place:

```
// Needs to be inside an `async` function!
const uri = await viewShot.current.capture();
try {
   const dataSave = {
   // etc
```

Comment: but how do I know when my function was executed?

Comment: // Needs to be inside an `async` function!
const uri = await viewShot.current.capture();
try {
   const dataSave = {
   // etc

Comment: Why do you need to know *when* it was executed? When it is executed, it does what it does.

Comment: It's because I'm taking a screenshot of my screen, and I want to save that print to storage.

Comment: And that's what `await` is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `async`/`await` syntax, you typically don't use `then` at all:

```
const page = await viewShot.current.capture();
try {
  const dataSave = {
    key: '1',
    title: 'Page One',

  };
  pagina.pushScreen.push(dataSave);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@pages', JSON.stringify(pagina));
  // alert('Página Salva!');
} catch (e) {
  alert('Erro ao salvar página');
}
```

**If** you're using `then` in a non-`async` function and want to keep doing that (rather than making it an `async` so you can use `await`), it's okay to pass an `async` function into `then`:

```
viewShot.current.capture.then(async (page) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
  try {
    const dataSave = {
      key: '1',
      title: 'Page One',

    };
    pagina.pushScreen.push(dataSave);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@pages', JSON.stringify(pagina));
    // alert('Página Salva!');
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Erro ao salvar página');
  }
});
```

Since `async` functions return promises, and fulfillment handlers are allowed to return promises in order to resolve the promise from `then` to the promise from the handler, that's okay.

---

Side note: The quoted code appears to be breaking one of the fundamental rules of promises: It doesn't handle rejection of the original promise, and doesn't appear to return the promise from `then` to anything else that would handle that rejection. The rule is: Handle rejection, or return the promise chain to something that will.